# How to overwrite dataframe column based on df.loc and map with datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I need to turn integers into datetime objects in a dataframe column, where the column has mixed datatypes. To know whether to apply the function, I need to reference a different column.

I have been able to solve this by turning the dataframe to a dictionary and iterating through it, but takes too long when the data gets too large.

When I try to solve this using .loc and .map it gives the correct output only when I don't set an equality.

Here is my dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'data' : 'abc', 'type': 'string'},
    {'data' : 1559347200000, 'type': 'int'},
    {'data': pd.to_datetime(1559347200000, unit='ms'), 'type':'datetime'}
    ])
```

When I run this the dataframe behaves as expected. Column: 'data' has mixed types, and column: 'type' I created to let me know what was in column 'data'.

Now I need to turn 'data' into datetime object where 'type' = 'int'.

```py
df.loc[df['type']=='int', 'data'].map(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x,unit='ms'))
```

The output of this '2019-06-01' with dtype: datetime64 looks correct.

However, When I set this equal to itself using:

```py
df.loc[df['type']=='int', 'data'] = df.loc[df['type']=='int', 'data'].map(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x,unit='ms'))
```

And then call:

```py
df.loc[df['type']=='int', 'data']
```

I get an output of 1559347200000000000

Why does it not return '2019-06-01' in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than check what column "type" is and then apply change to column "data" based on what you find in column "type", do a shortcut. Check type of value in "data" column inside lambda expression, and convert to datetime if it's of int type, otherwise no change.

```
df=df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,unit='ms') if type(x) is int else x)
```

Output:

```
                  data      type
0                  abc    string
1  2019-06-01 00:00:00       int
2  2019-06-01 00:00:00  datetime
```

Comment: My project requires me to use the type column. @hknjj. Its not enough to transform all instances where dtype of 'data' = int. We must only transform where type = 'int'